# how to use materialize with angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

Its been 2 days i am stuck with this issue ,Fairly new to angular 2 so i am trying to use materialize with angular 2 i resolved couple of errors it was asking to update to typscript version i updated that now there are more issues. Just wanted to understand what is the best way to use materialize with angular2 ?

package.json

```
{
  "name": "SLA",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "test": "ng test",
    "build": "ng build && node server.js",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0-rc0",
    "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
    "angular2-materialize": "^15.1.10",
    "axios": "^0.17.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^2.2.4",
    "materialize-css": "^0.100.2",
    "oploggery": "^0.1.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.28.3",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "~4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.6.1"
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { StreamComponent } from './stream/stream.component';
import { StreamService } from './stream.service';
import { routing } from './app.routes';
import { MaterializeModule } from "angular2-materialize";
import { SearchComponent } from './search/search.component';
import { DetailComponent } from './detail/detail.component';
import { SlaChartComponent } from './sla-chart/sla-chart.component';
import {MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material';
const ROUTES = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'app',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'stream',
    component: StreamComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    StreamComponent,
    SearchComponent,
    DetailComponent,
    SlaChartComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    MaterializeModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    routing

  ],
  providers: [StreamService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

ERROR

```
Metadata version mismatch for module WebstormProjects/slariskanalysisgui/node_modules/@angular/material/core/typings/index.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol AppModule in WebstormProjects/slariskan
    alysisgui/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in C:/Users/sh529u/WebstormProjects/slariskanalysisgui/src/app/app.module.ts
```

Comment: Looking to your dependencies, I see that you're using Angular Material too. That is really necessary? Try updating Angular to the last version. Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't give many of your code files, it is hard to answer your specific scenario. Regarding the question **how to use materialize with angular 2?** though, this is a demonstratable way to get the two to work together.

- Create a new project with the cli `ng new ng-materialize`
- Run `npm install --save materialize-css @types/materialize-css`
- Update `app.component.html`

  ```
  <ul #collapse class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>First</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>Second</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Third</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  ```
- Update `app.component.ts'

  ```
  import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

  import * as $ from 'jquery';
  import 'materialize-css';

  @Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
  })
  export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('collapse') c_element: ElementRef;

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
      $(this.c_element.nativeElement).collapsible();
    }
  }
  ```